# What is the query to find the percentage of the memory used in mysql database schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We want to schedule an event if the memory of the mysql schema exceeds 70% of the total size. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2393/determine-sql-server-memory-use-by-database-and-object/

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
select table_schema, sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB 
from information_schema.tables 
group by 1;
```

Comment: Getting the following error.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select table_schema, sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB from ' at line 1

Comment: I checked this query and i getting perfect result.